# ASP.NET GridView fail to sort a Date passed as string

Tags: sorting, date, gridview

Hi I am building a site which has a gridview with AutoGenerateColumns = True, the issue that I am having is the Sort condition using a dataview does not work correctly for example.  If I have the following records already displayed on the gridview:

- Name            Address              Date (MM/DD/YYYY)
- Julio XYZ      Australia              12/25/2010
- David 1234  New Zealand        12/26/2010
- Erika 5555   Singapore            12/14/2011

If I do the sorting this way:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetDataTable(Me.GetQuery(Sentence, params))
Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView
dv.Sort = SortExpression & " " & SortDirection
gv.DataSource = dv
gv.DataBind()
```

The result in the grid is :

- Name              Address         Date (MM/DD/YYYY)
- Erika 5555     Singapore       12/14/2011
- Julio XYZ        Australia         12/25/2010
- David 1234    New Zealand   12/26/2010

So the problem it seems to be the sort is only taking in consideration part of the date only the first five characters instead of the whole string.

The values for SortExpression is the ColumnName for Date which in the datasource is CallDate and the SorDirection Value is ASC

The Me.GetDataTable(Me.GetQuery(Sentence,paramas)) is just a way to populate the datatable with the records from the Database.

Another thing, sadly I cannot change the format of the Date because is a business requirement to be presented that way, also I am not allow to use third party controls because the budget of the project. :-(

Thanks for the any idea in advance.

Comment: It hasn't failed to sort correctlt. You gave it a string and standard sort of strings 12/14/2011 < 12/25/2010. Once you converted it toaa string, it is no longer a date. Either pass in a date and rely on the grid to format it based on the setting of the application / user / machine running the application. Or see if you can convert back to a date in sort expression, with acast or convert

Comment: Thanks for your response,  but how do I tell the grid if the columns are AutoGenerated, that column will be a Date value and its own format?

Comment: Well you said it was passed as a string, so it should be just a question of finding out where that's done and passing it as a date.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to confirm that whether your **Date** is DateTime type, if yes,

please try to sample as below, hope these will give you a hand.

```
                Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetDataTable(Me.GetQuery(Sentence, params))
                dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Date ASC" ''Sort with Asc.
                gv.DataSource = dt
                gv.DataBind()
```